# Using -contains in powershell is not working

Tags: powershell

I wrote a Powershell Script to Remove/Create a Sample Biztalk Application.

Whenever i try to create a application.
Am checking is there any application exists already using the below condition

```
[void] [System.reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM")
$Catalog = New-Object Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM.BtsCatalogExplorer
$Catalog.ConnectionString = "SERVER=$SQLServerInstance;DATABASE=$SQLCatalog;Integrated Security=SSPI" 

if($Catalog.Applications -contains $AppName)
{
write-eventlog -logname "$logname" -Source "$Source" -eventid "$eventidError" -message "$errormessage" -entrytype "Error" -Computername "$Server"
}
else
{
....
invoke-expression $Addapp
}
```

For the first time its creating the application. but when i try to run the second time(already app created). its stil executing the true case. it's not executing the else part.

Please Advice. Is there any other property in order to refresh to get the newly added applications.

Comment: can you show what's in the $catalog.applications ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.biztalk.explorerom.btscatalogexplorer%28v=bts.80%29.aspx) `$Catalog.Applications` is an array of `Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM.Application` objects, whereas you need an array with the name strings of these objects. Try something like this:

```
if ( ($Catalog.Applications | select -Expand Name) -contains $AppName ) {
  ...
  Write-EventLog ...
} else {
  ...
  Invoke-Expression $Addapp
}
```